# How can you copy a weight paint from a Bone in one object to a bone in another object

Tags: animation, objects, armature, bones, weight-painting

So I have two objects that are identical except for the weight painting. I want to get the properties of the weight paint from one bone onto another bone on the other object. Does anyone know how to solve this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, even if the two objects are not identical.

Move the two objects in the same spot, select the destination object (or objects), THEN shift select the source, then press F3 (search operator) and type "data", choose the "Transfer mesh data" operator, choose "vertex groups". If the objects are the same all others default options should be OK.

After generating the copied vertex groups, you can rename them accordingly with the names of the new deforming bones